# How can I do Java annotation like @name("Luke") with no attribute inside parenthesis?

Tags: java, attributes, annotations, default, parentheses

How I can do custom Java annotation with no attribute name inside parentheses?

I don't want this: `@annotation_name(att=valor)`. I just want like in Servlets, i.e:

```
@WebServlet("/main")
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Define the annotation with an attribute named `value`, then the attribute name can be omitted:

```
@interface CustomAnnotation
{
    String value();
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
@CustomAnnotation("/main")
// ...
```

The special attribute name `value` is described in chapter ["9.6.1. Annotation Interface Elements" of Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1):

> By convention, the name of the sole element in a single-element annotation interface is `value`. Linguistic support for this convention is provided by single-element annotations ([§9.7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3)).

Comment: Don't compile :( and in Eclipse throw a error saying missing attribute

Comment: But doesn't work yet :(                                               @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Get {

 String name();
 
}                                                                     =>  @Get("hi")
    public void inserir()  THROWS AN EXCEPTION

Comment: Just like pointed in other answers it doesn't have to be the only attribute.

Answer (score 38):

You specify an attribute named value:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String value();

}
```

This doesn't have to be the only attribute if they have default values:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String value();
    int myInteger() default 0;

}
```

But if you want to explicitly assign a value to the attribute other than value, you then must explicitly assign value. That is to say:

```
@MyAnnotation("foo")
@MyAnnotation(value = "foo", myInteger = 1)
```

works

but

```
@MyAnnotatino("foo", myInteger = 1)
```

does not

Answer (score 20):

Quoting [Annotations official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html):

> If there is just one element named `value`, then the name may be omitted, as in:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void myMethod() { }
```

This is how this annotation is defined:

```
public @interface SuppressWarnings {
  String[] value();
}
```

As you can see the documentation isn't entirely right, other attributes are also allowed ("*just one element*"), see [`WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) - but the one named `value` is treated differently.